# What can I call someone who has many unfinished tasks on his hands?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a guy at work who keeps sending me e-mails with the **outstanding** things to do, i.e. tasks that I need to tackle but haven't gotten to yet.

Would it be correct to say that ***he is an outstander***? Is that a real word? Is there a better term?

Comment: The verb _to outstand_ means ["to endure beyond"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outstand) in a positive sense. So, despite the fact that _outstander_ is not a word according to English dictionaries, the use of the word it is derived from, _outstand_, would be incorrect in this context.

Comment: Please clarify your pronouns.  Who are "he" and "me" in your example, and  which of them does this word modify?

Comment: As Tim Romano commented, clarification is required for this question to be answered.  I'm afraid, otherwise it's in jeopardy of being closed for being unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

*Procrastinator, dilly-dallier, dawdler* may be close to what you are asking.

"*He is a dilly-dallier, no wonder he has more pending works than accomplished ones*."